# Can I change the default trash sounds?

Tags: customization

I'd love to change the default empty trash / move to trash sounds. I found [this on Github](https://github.com/karmi/dotfiles/blob/master/mac/__system_preferences.sh), which is a script to change a bunch of defaults. The default alert is mentioned, but nothing about the trash.

Alternately, [this other AskDifferent question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60017/can-the-alert-sound-in-mountain-lions-notification-center-be-customized) discusses how to add a custom alert sound. Does anyone know the path to where the trash sounds are stored? Could I just replace the sound file as in the linked SO thread?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to change `*.aif` sounds in:

```
 /System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component/Contents/SharedSupport/SystemSounds/finder
```

There are:
`empty trash.aif` and `move to trash.aif` (self explanatory). I recomend to make backup of those files before swap.